# Configuration class not found for JAR with Hibernate dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to use hibernate in a sample, but cannot run it. Here is ma main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory factory;

        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

        System.out.println("**Example : Hibernate 4 SessionFactory**");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've build it with

```
mvn clean install assembly:single
```

but when I've runned JAR, I've got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 1 more
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hibernate-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

*EDIT*: I've opened result JAR with JD-Gui and discovered that there is Configuration class in my JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get two jar files with your maven configuration. If you try running hibernate-test-1.0.jar you will get the error you are getting because it doesn't contain the dependencies. It is of no use by itself.

If you run hibernate-test-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar you will not get the ClassNotFoundException. That jar file is created with the maven-assembly-plugin and it contains all the dependencies you defined in you pom.

Comment: Oh, it was my fault - I've forget to change JAR name. Thanks